# Readline parser doesn't read correctly from serial port - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I have a connection with POS (point of sale) device. I send it information in hex code and the device prints a receipt.

My problem is that the parser (`Readline`) doesn't work. When I try to use `parser.on("data", console.log)`, it doesn't return anything.
Here is my code:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');// include the library
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
const SERVER_PORT = 7000;               // port number for the webSocket server
const wss = new WebSocketServer({port: SERVER_PORT}); // the webSocket server
var connections = new Array;          // list of connections to the server
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;

wss.on('connection', handleConnection);
const myPort = new SerialPort("COM3", {
    baudRate: 115200,
});
myPort.on('open', showPortOpen);
myPort.on('close', showPortClose);
myPort.on('error', showError);

const parser = myPort.pipe(new Readline('\r\n'))
console.log('parser setup');
parser.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data received: ', data);
});

function handleConnection(client) {
    console.log("New Connection"); // you have a new client
    connections.push(client); // add this client to the connections array

    client.on('message', sendToSerial); // when a client sends a message,

    client.on('close', function() { // when a client closes its connection
        console.log("connection closed"); // print it out
        var position = connections.indexOf(client); // get the client's position in the array
        connections.splice(position, 1); // and delete it from the array
    });
}

function sendToSerial(data) {
    console.log("sending to serial: " + data);
    myPort.write(data, 'hex');
}

// This function broadcasts messages to all webSocket clients
function broadcast(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (myConnection in connections) {  // iterate over the array of connections
        connections[myConnection].send(JSON.stringify(data)); // send the data to each connection
    }
}

function showPortOpen() {
   console.log('port open. Data rate: ' + myPort.baudRate);
}

function readSerialData(data) {
   // if there are webSocket connections, send the serial data
   // to all of them:
   if (connections.length > 0) {
     broadcast(data);
   }
}

function showPortClose() {
   console.log('port closed.');
}

function showError(error) {
   console.log('Serial port error: ' + error);
}
```

I receive messages, but they are split and I want to send to client whole message. I tried to define the parser and after that to pipe it. I tried to set parser in SerialPort constructor, changed the delimiter, but no result.
I think that my error is something with the parser.

Here you can see that doesn't return `console.log`
[image]

And here is the result if I use

```
myPort.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data received: ', data);
});
```

[image]

The idea is to get whole message after every command and send it to the client.

Comment: You need to concatenate the message by yourself. Through the serial port you'll always get a stream of data. Just concatenate until some `EOF` and handle it afterwards.

Comment: So after every command when it is called `myPort.on('data')`  code execute `function broadcast` and send the message to the client. This concatenate have to be in client side, right? Or how can I make the concatenation after all messages are read and after that to send it to the client?

Comment: You could do it either on server or on client side. You could implement a callback which calls the function `function broadcast` as soon as the full message is received (this is what i would recommend).

Comment: I've just read the documentation of Readline and the delimiter should handle this for you. In this case: `parser.on('data', data => broadcast(data))` should work. Check your messages with `parser.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()))` and check if your delimiter is set right.

Comment: Yes, I read it also many times at many places, but `parser.on('data', data => broadcast(data))` doesn't work like `parser` is not valid or it isn't piped to `myPort`.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your question. Now i get your problem. Serialport has a readline api:                                                                                                     
`var port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty-usbserial1', {
       parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('\n')
});`                                                                                                                         - With this you could try: `myPort.on('data', data => broadcast(data.toString())`

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in readline api from `SerialPort`:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');// include the library
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
const SERVER_PORT = 7000;               // port number for the webSocket server
const wss = new WebSocketServer({port: SERVER_PORT}); // the webSocket server
var connections = new Array;          // list of connections to the server
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;

wss.on('connection', handleConnection);

const myPort = new SerialPort('COM3', {
  baudRate: 115200,
  parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('\r\n')
});

myPort.on('open', showPortOpen);
myPort.on('close', showPortClose);
myPort.on('error', showError);

myPort.on('data', data => readSerialData(data.toString());


// ...

function broadcast(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (myConnection in connections) {
        connections[myConnection].send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}

// ...

function readSerialData(data) {
   // if there are webSocket connections, send the serial data
   // to all of them:
   if (connections.length > 0) {
     broadcast(data);
   }
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The message is split again. So I want it whole message to decode it by hex code. Did the problem come from parser?

[image]

Comment: What have you done to get the output above? Did you apply my solution to your code? Please be more specific, so others can better understand the problem.

Comment: Yes, I set port like this
`const myPort = new SerialPort("COM3", {
 baudRate: 115200,
 parser: new SerialPort.parsers.Readline('\r\n')
});`
and
`myPort.on('data', data => readSerialData(JSON.stringify(data)));`
just change type of returned data, but it return two messages, now i'll try go store it in some variable i after that decode it

Comment: Okay so your root question is solved in this case? What kind of data do you expect to come from your serial port? May i can help you then to handle it correctly.

Comment: Question now is how to merge all messages and when last message is read from server to send it to client. Then there I'll decode message on client side.

Comment: The first message you receive is empty or useless as you can see. You could merge them with temp variable. But i would just send all of them to your client, decode it to a string and display it if `string.length > 0` . I'm done for today, good luck with the rest. If my answer was helpfull, i'm happy about a vote.